# How prevent pd.pivot_table from sorting columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the following long df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'stations':["Toronto","Toronto","Toronto","New York","New York","New York"],'forecast_date':["Jul 30","Jul 31","Aug 1","Jul 30","Jul 31","Aug 1"],'low':[58,57,59,70,72,71],'high':[65,66,64,88,87,86]})
print(df)
```

I want to pivot the table to a wide df that looks like this:

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNNZc.png)

so I used the following function:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index = 'stations', columns = "forecast_date", values = ["high","low"],aggfunc = "first").reset_index()
print(df)
```

but with this, I get the following df:

[Output Received (Undesired)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqZEa.png)

So basically pd.pivot_table seems to be sorting the columns alphabetically, whereas I want it to be sorted in chronological order

Any help would be appreciated,

(*Note that the dates are continuously changing, so other months will have a similar problem*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to prevent the sorting, but you can always enforce the original ordering by using `.reindex` with the unique values from the column!

```py
table = df.pivot_table(index = 'stations', columns = "forecast_date", values = ["high","low"],aggfunc = "first")

print(
    table
)
               high                 low              
forecast_date Aug 1 Jul 30 Jul 31 Aug 1 Jul 30 Jul 31
stations                                             
New York         86     88     87    71     70     72
Toronto          64     65     66    59     58     57


print(
    table.reindex(columns=df['forecast_date'].unique(), level='forecast_date')
)
                high                 low             
forecast_date Jul 30 Jul 31 Aug 1 Jul 30 Jul 31 Aug 1
stations                                             
New York          88     87    86     70     72    71
Toronto           65     66    64     58     57    59
```

Note that this is different than sorting in chronological order. To do that you would have to cast to a `datetime` and sort on that.